# Counting the number of colors in a JPG

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get the number of colours in a JPG file. I have followed a tutorial and created an white image with a black circle in it, so the number of colors in the image is 2 but from the code and the outcome is showing as just one color which is white.

How do I fix the code so that all the colors in the image is shown in the table outcome:

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter
import prettytable

img = Image.open("bnw.jpg")
size = w, h = img.size
data = img.load()

colors = []
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        color = data[x, y]
    hex_color = '#'+''.join([hex(c)[2:].rjust(2, '0') for c in color])
    colors.append(hex_color)

pt = prettytable.PrettyTable(['Color', 'Count'])

for color, count in Counter(colors).items():
    pt.add_row([color, count])

print(pt)
```

Here is the outcome:

```
+---------+-------+
|  Color  | Count |
+---------+-------+
| #ffffff |  1000 |
+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only call `colors.append(hex_color)` for the last pixel in each `x`.  I think you meant this:

```
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter
import prettytable

img = Image.open("bnw.jpg")
size = w, h = img.size
data = img.load()

colors = []
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        color = data[x, y]
        hex_color = '#'+''.join([hex(c)[2:].rjust(2, '0') for c in color])
        colors.append(hex_color)

pt = prettytable.PrettyTable(['Color', 'Count'])

for color, count in Counter(colors).items():
    pt.add_row([color, count])

print(pt)
```